# edit entry on special position in a grid

Tags: python, dictionary, grid, tkinter

I have a function creating entries via grid() like this: (replace while-loop with function, this should just show you what it looks like  later)

```
from Tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

index=0

while index < 10:

     col0 = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
     col0.grid(row=index,column=0)
     col0.insert('0.0',"name")
     col1 = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
     col1.grid(row=index,column=1)
     col1.insert('0.0',"attribute #1")
     col2 = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
     col2.grid(row=index,column=2)
     col2.insert('0.0',"attribute #2")
     col3 = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
     col3.grid(row=index,column=3)
     col3.insert('0.0',"counter")
     index+=1

root.mainloop()
```

so on special events the function is called and creates a new entry (a new row). but if there is already an entry for this event, i just want to increase the counter.

the eventnames and their entryrows (index) are saved in a dictionary, so i do have the row and column, but how can i actually access col3 now?

i planned to get the counter via col3.get(), but it is called col3 in every row, so how could i specify it?

is it alternatively possible to put col0,col1,col2 etc into a kind of structure (like a dictionary), so access them via col0[name].insert()... (name is unique)? i tried that but that did not work out (which does not mean its impossible i hope, i am just quite new to python)

does anyone have any suggestions or solutions to my problem?

Comment: use `for index in range(10):` instead of `while index<10:`, and lose the `index=0` and `index+=1` lines, just as a python pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save references to all the Text widgets that you create:

```
colHeaders = ["name", "attribute #1", "attribute #2", "counter"]
myTextWidgets = []
for index in range(10):
    subList = []
    for i, header in enumerate(colHeaders):
        text = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
        text.grid(row=index,column=i)
        text.insert('0.0',header)
        subList.append(text)
    myTextWidgets.append(subList)
```

This would allow you to access each widget by it's row/column:

```
myTextWidgets[0][1].config(bg="purple")
```

You could easily append a new row to this structure like so:

```
subList = []
for i, header in enumerate(colHeaders):
    text = Text(root,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
    text.grid(row=len(myTextWidgets),column=i)
    text.insert('0.0', header)
    subList.append(text)
myTextWidgets.append(subList)
```

With this structure, it's not the *names* that are unique, but the *positions* of each cell.

Comment: this solution worked out quite well, tweaked it a little bit to fit my program, but the list in list thing was what i aimed for. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary idea is good.  I've come up with a bare-bones implementation here... (classes are the best way to keep data persistent between function calls.)

In this example, your Text widgets can be accessed via `app.ObjGrid[(row,col)]` or access it via `self.ObjGrid[(row,col)]` if you're doing it from a method.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class TextGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.ObjGrid={}
        self.index=1
        for i in xrange(10):
            self.addRow()

    def addRow(self,index=None):
        """
        add a row of widgets at row=<index>.  If index is omitted, add the next row
        If index is on the grid already, prints "Increment counter?" since I don't
        know what you mean by that
        """

        if(index is None):
           index=self.index+1
           self.index+=1
        if (index,0) in self.ObjGrid:
            print "Increment counter?"  #probably replace this code...
            return

        self.ObjGrid[(index,0)] = col0 = tk.Text(self,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
        col0.grid(row=index,column=0)
        col0.insert('0.0',"name")
        self.ObjGrid[(index,1)] = col1 = tk.Text(self,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
        col1.grid(row=index,column=1)
        col1.insert('0.0',"attribute #1")
        self.ObjGrid[(index,2)] = col2 = tk.Text(self,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
        col2.grid(row=index,column=2)
        col2.insert('0.0',"attribute #2")
        self.ObjGrid[(index,3)] = col3 = tk.Text(self,width=20, height=1, bg='white')
        col3.grid(row=index,column=3)
        col3.insert('0.0',"counter")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=TextGrid(root)
    app.grid(row=0,column=0)
    app.addRow(3) #Shouldn't do anything
    app.addRow() #Should add another row to the end.
    print(type(app.ObjGrid[(2,3)])) #tkinter text widget.
    root.mainloop()
```

As a note on style ...

```
from XXX import *
```

is typically frowned upon.

```
import XXX as short_name_that_is_easy_to_remember
```

is generally preferred.  Also, when doing stuff in Tkinter, I find that it is always easiest to start off from a class.  Build a *widget*.  It is trivial to change a widget into an application, but it can be nearly impossible to change an application into a widget.  The easiest way to build a widget is to inherit from `Frame` and then pack other widgets onto that frame as I show above.

Comment: i already did the import-stuff in my code, same for the class ;) the code above was just to explain my problem, but still, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible, I'd say it's preferable for a situation like this. Here's one simple approach:

```
attr_names = ['name', 'attribute #1', 'attribute #2', 'counter']
def make_text_field(row, col, attr_name):
    text = Text(root, width=20, height=1, bg='white')
    text.grid(row=row, column=col)
    text.insert('0.0', attr_name)

text_fields = {}
for row, col in itertools.product(xrange(10), xrange(4)):
    text_fields[row, col] = make_text_field(row, col, attr_names[col])
```

This stores each field individually in `text_fields`, with a `(row, col)` tuple as the key. You could also create a list of lists; since you want to access whole columns, you might prefer that. You could preallocate the list and use `product` as above, but for simplicity, here's another approach:

```
list_of_cols = list()
for col in xrange(4):
    col = list()
    list_of_cols.append(col)
    for row in xrange(10):
        col.append(make_text_field(row, col, attr_names[col]))
```